# SQL Pivot on Dynamic Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, ssms, dynamic-pivot

I'm attempting to pivot counts on dates in SSMS with a dynamic date range (previous 90 days), but my dates are out of order in the results.  Is there a way to put an ORDER BY in this query?  Or, does someone have a better way to pivot on a dynamic date range?

```
declare @cols as nvarchar(max);
declare @query as nvarchar(max); 

select @cols = stuff((select distinct 
                             ',' + quotename(ColumnDate) 
                        from 
                             [Database].[Schema].[ExampleTable] as et
                         for 
                             xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');

select @query = 'select *
                   from 
                        (select et.Place                   
                                ,et.ColumnDate
                                ,et.ValueToAggregate
                           from 
                                [Database].[Schema].[ExampleTable] as et) as t 
                  pivot   
                        (count(ValueToAggregate) 
                         for ColumnDate in( ' + @cols + ')' + ')  as p; ';
                        
execute(@query);




The dates in my results are out of order...

Place               |3/25/2021  |4/19/2021  |2/21/2021  |3/22/2021  |2/14/2021  |2/11/2021
Test_Facility_1     |6          |5          |0          |2          |0          |3
Test_Facility_2     |1          |0          |0          |2          |2          |2
Test_Facility_3     |0          |1          |0          |1          |1          |2
Test_Facility_4     |124        |111        |85         |83         |95         |97
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` in your first SELECT statement between the `FROM` and the `FOR XML`. However, exactly which expression to use in the order by may depend on the data type of column `ColumnDate`. If it is a date column, then you can just use

```
ORDER BY ColumnDate
```

Comment: Thanks @FrankPl  it worked when I used ORDER BY ',' + quotename(ColumnDate)

Comment: I'm noticing that my results are showing NULLs instead of zeroes.  I've tried placing ISNULL and Coalesce around the value that needs to be aggregated.  How do pull in zeroes for NULLs?

Comment: @DavidMarshall That would be a different question.